Asana connecting to PowerBI | Missing Column
I am trying to connect Asana to PowerBI. I am using the Asana connector available in PowerBI. All other fields are shown except one custom field in powerbi.
I have expanded on the custom fields and project custom fields but unable to find this particular column. It's not reflecting at all in powerbi when I load with the connector. It should have been loaded along with other custom fields. I need your expert advice on how to get this missing column in PowerBI which is available in Asana.

Try the suggestion at https://forum.asana.com/t/load-asana-custom-fields-via-power-bi-api/87127
